# GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

Tags: android, google-signin

I am developing a login system using google sign in by firebase,I have done everything as mentioned in the docs still I am unable to sign in.I guess there is a problem in the try and catch block. The code stops to run at this line and ends up in the catch block.

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                progress.show();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

            } catch (ApiException e) {

                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                //  Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed Sign in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your log to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed some configuration while using Firebase Gmail Authentication. I am mentioning below the working Github Repository. It will help you to get your code work.

**Github Repository**

[Androchef Firebase Auth Login](https://github.com/happysingh23828/Ultimate-FireBase-Learning-AndroidChef/tree/FirebaseAuth)

**Commit Gmail Authentication Commit**.

[Google sign in Added](https://github.com/happysingh23828/Ultimate-FireBase-Learning-AndroidChef/commit/bae58adf8138dd937619330cf110ff7879abf7cb)

**Blog Post about Firebase Google Authentication**

[Firebase Google Authentication – Example](https://androchef.com/firebase-google-authentication-example/)